# Почему `onErrorReturnItem()` все равно возвращает `NullPointerException` RxJava2?

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Есть вот такой метод

```
private Single<List<String>> getOtherEmployeesSingle()
{
    return Observable.fromIterable(mFilteredOtherEmployees)//
                     .map(//
                             FilterableEmployee::getStorageRoomCode//
                     )//
                     .toList()//
                     .onErrorReturnItem(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

В котором `mFilteredOtherEmployees` возможно еще не инициализирован и он `null` и для этого я добавил `onErrorReturnItem(new ArrayList<>())` и расчитываю на то, что если будет ошибка то мне вернется просто `ArrayList()` , но нет, мне все равно возвращается `NullPointerException`

Что не так?

Comment: На сколько я помню, `onErrorReturnItem()` работает только с тем обсерваблом, на котором он был вызван. Попробуйте поставить его перед `map`.

Comment: @eugeneek точно, наверное так и есть, поэтому он не срабатывает... Но я не могу поставить его перед `map` так как он хочет в аргумент получить тип такой же с которым работает `Observable` то есть такой же как и у переменной `mFilteredOtherEmployees` , но мне нужно вернуть тип который получается после `map`  и после `toList()` (в данном случае это будет `ArrayList<String>`), понимаете, что я имею ввиду?

Comment: Нужно указать тип для Observable в <>, должно помочь

Comment: @Kota1921 Он не дает указывать тип... Или я не так понял

Comment: Добавьте стектрейс...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не правильно используете метод fromIterable.
В методе есть проверка, что входной параметр не может быть null.

```
public static <T> Observable<T> fromIterable(Iterable<? extends T> source) {
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(source, "source is null");
        return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableFromIterable<T>(source));
    }
```

Касательно вашего кода нужно сделать так:

```
    Observable.fromCallable((Callable<List<String>>) () -> mFilteredOtherEmployees)
            .flatMapIterable(value -> value)
            .map(FilterableEmployee::getStorageRoomCode)
            .toList()
            .onErrorReturnItem(new ArrayList<String>())
```